# Foreach loop skipping over first item without any sort of pop/remove function

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to create a simple program to calculate balance of transaction. Everything works fine, except for the fact that my programs skips over the first item in the list. I'm trying to find out what I missed...

Basically the input is of the format ('D 100' , 'W 50' ) etc. where D denotes deposit and W denotes Withdrawal. The initial balance is assumed to be 0.

Here is my code:

```
# While loop for continuous input
def WhileInputActive(function,List=None):
        while True:
                inputVariable = input();
                if (inputVariable is None) or (not inputVariable):
                        break;
                if (List is None):
                        function(inputVariable);
                else:
                        function(List,inputVariable);


def PlaceInList(List,Input):
    List.append(Input);


def CalculateTransactionBalance():
    Input = input();
    List = []
    amount = 0 
    WhileInputActive(PlaceInList,List)
    for item in List:
        Type=item[0]
        string = ''
        for num in item:
            if(num.isdigit()):
                string+=str(num)
        if(Type == 'D'):
            amount += int(string)
        else:
            amount -= int(string)
    print(int(amount))

CalculateTransactionBalance()
```

Here is the input:

```
D 300
D 300
W 200
D 100
```

Here is the output:

```
200
```

The expected output is 500, but the program skips over the first entry (i did a bit of digging on the cause for printing 200 instead of 500)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call input() outside your `WhileInputActive` function and don't do anything with the data it read. Specifically, this line inside `CalculateTransactionBalance:`

```
Input = input();
```